# Self hosted drop.io clone?

Tags: linux, php

Anyone have any pointers to some LAMP-based code to get the functionality of drop.io (send large files) on a self hosted site?

Comment: On Software Recommendations SE: [File hosting service similar to drop.io (but self-hosted and free/libre)](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/2479/60)

Answer (score 1):

It's not LAMP-hosted, but [Tonido](http://www.tonido.com/) is free and works on Windows, OS X and Linux.  It's great for sharing files and it connects directly to the host machines instead of hosting the files on 3rd party servers.

Comment: Thanks.. tho I'm really looking for something that operates the way drop.io does. Upload to your own server and generate a unique URL for that item - ideally it'd have the option to assign a password, and should expire after some definable amount of time.